# MySQL: Group result of timestamp depending data in columns

Tags: mysql

I have data like this for a period over 3 years:

| TimeStamp | Consumption |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-16 00:15:00 | 48 |
| 2022-01-16 00:30:00 | 38 |
| 2022-01-16 00:45:00 | 40 |
| 2022-01-16 01:00:00 | 346 |
| 2022-01-16 01:15:00 | 182 |
| 2022-01-16 01:30:00 | 38 |
| 2022-01-16 01:45:00 | 44 |
| 2022-01-16 02:00:00 | 53 |

I would like to query and group the sum of consumption over a month grouped by years. Every year shall have its own column like this:

| Month | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 616522 | 251669 |
| 2 |  | 661909 |  |
| 3 |  | 476928 |  |
| 4 | 340073 | 417943 |  |
| 5 | 343518 | 363774 |  |
| 6 | 333023 | 383071 |  |
| 7 | 376138 | 372729 |  |
| 8 | 451099 | 338588 |  |
| 9 | 333298 | 326093 |  |
| 10 | 399301 | 363540 |  |
| 11 | 421328 | 458276 |  |
| 12 | 553438 | 546010 |  |

All I already managed to query was:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(TimeStamp, '%M %Y'),
    sum(Consumption)
FROM
    SolarEdge_EnergyDetails
GROUP BY
    date_format(TimeStamp, '%M %Y');
```

resulting in this:

| DATE_FORMAT(TimeStamp, '%M %Y') | sum(Consumption) |
| --- | --- |
| April 2020 | 340073 |
| April 2021 | 417943 |
| August 2020 | 451099 |
| August 2021 | 338588 |
| December 2020 | 553438 |
| December 2021 | 546010 |
| February 2021 | 661909 |
| January 2021 | 616522 |
| January 2022 | 251669 |
| July 2020 | 376138 |
| July 2021 | 372729 |
| June 2020 | 333023 |
| June 2021 | 383071 |
| March 2021 | 476928 |
| May 2020 | 343518 |
| May 2021 | 363774 |
| November 2020 | 421328 |
| November 2021 | 458276 |
| October 2020 | 399301 |
| October 2021 | 363540 |
| September 2020 | 333298 |
| September 2021 | 326093 |

How do I get my results sort per year in columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a static query like thus, but you must change it every year

```
SELECT 
MONTH(ts) AS MONTH,
sum(IF(YEAR(ts) = 2020,con,NULL)) AS '2020',
sum(IF(YEAR(ts) = 2021,con,NULL)) AS '2021',
sum(IF(YEAR(ts) = 2022,con,NULL)) AS '2022'

FROM SolarEdge_EnergyDetails
GROUP BY MONTH(ts)
ORDER BY ts;
```

Or you change the column name to relativ like this:

```
SELECT 
MONTH(ts) AS MONTH,
sum(IF(YEAR(ts) = YEAR(now()),con,NULL)) AS 'this year',
sum(IF(YEAR(ts) = YEAR(now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR),con,NULL)) AS 'last year',
sum(IF(YEAR(ts) = YEAR(now() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR),con,NULL)) AS '2 years ago'

FROM SolarEdge_EnergyDetails
WHERE YEAR(ts) >= YEAR(now() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
GROUP BY MONTH(ts)
ORDER BY ts;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the following error message with the first example:

````ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'con' in 'field list'````. 

The error message is identical in the second example, which is understandable.

Comment: that are my fieldnames: ts = TimeStamp and con = Consumption . you must change it for your sample

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `pivot` you can try to use outer join with condition aggregate function.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    t1.Months 'Month',
    sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(t2.TimeStamp) = 2020 THEN t2.Consumption END) '2020',
    sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(t2.TimeStamp) = 2021 THEN t2.Consumption END) '2021',
    sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(t2.TimeStamp) = 2022 THEN t2.Consumption END) '2022'
FROM
(
    SELECT Months
    FROM 
    (   SELECT 1 Months
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 7
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 8
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 9
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 10
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 11
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 12
    ) t1
) t1
LEFT JOIN SolarEdge_EnergyDetails t2 ON t1.Months = MONTH(t2.TimeStamp)
GROUP BY
    t1.Months
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ba380/1/0)**:

Comment: This works out of the box!

Comment: @Christian What do you mean?